# Continuously hold a button CGEvent

Tags: swift

This question is a follow up from a very old post:

[CGEventPost - hold a key (shift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773225/cgeventpost-hold-a-key-shift)

I am building a SwiftUI virtual keyboard. Like a real keyboard, I have UIButtons that resemble the hardware buttons ( key `a`, `s`, `d`, etc ) which the user can click with their mouse. The user can also toggle to keep a button pressed.

I can send keyDown events using a function below, but an unable to **keep** a keyboard key held down. Inferring that my users want to hold every button until released, how would I send a CGEvent that would tell the macOS that the key with `keyCode == a` is being held by the user?

```
private func pressButton(_ keyCode: UInt16) {
    // create a key down event
    let eventDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: keyCode, keyDown: true)
    // post the key down event
    eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

I tried intentionally only setting the keyDown event without the keyUp event ( as seen in the above function ), but I get an equivalent of a button press as opposed to hold. I also tried to use timers to fire the `pressButton` method periodically to keep sending button down events, but ran into the issue of "the events are being sent too fast or too slow", in comparison what would happen if i were to hold that specific button on my keyboard.

A useful thread: [Simulate keypress using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484330/simulate-keypress-using-swift)